# Return only the values that match a certain criteria

Tags: mysql, count, criteria, distinct

I have

```
ID   Rank

11   1  
11   2  
22   1  
22   2  
22   3  
33   1  
33   3  
44   1  
55   1  
55   2
```

I Want

```
11  
44  
55
```

That is, I want to return only the IDs that have never been in a rank of '3'.

UPDATE - I figured another way, rather simpler, to do this in addition to the answer below.

```
SELECT ID FROM
(  
  SELECT ID, SUM(CASE WHEN Rank = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) flag FROM 
  (  
    SELECT ID, Rank FROM T1
  ) a  
  GROUP BY ID    
) b  
WHERE flag = 0;
```

Comment: a few things, please see below.

Comment: Below? Below where? Put them in your _question_.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I posted another answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    yt1.ID
FROM
    yourTable yt1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM yourTable yt2
        WHERE 
            yt1.ID = yt2.ID 
            AND yt2.Rank = 3
    )
```

Or, using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    yt1.ID
FROM
    yourTable yt1
    LEFT JOIN yourTable yt2 ON yt1.ID = yt2.ID AND yt2.Rank = 3
WHERE
    yt2.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: gud way but no need you can do it very easy way aslso

Comment: @Michael both `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN` work as expected. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an array of unique ids, then check those for a rank of three. Those that don't, put them into a final array.

```
$idArray = array();
$noThreeArray = array();

$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM yourTable';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $idArray[] = $row['ID'];
}
foreach($idArray as $id){
   $query = 'SELECT ID FROM yourTable WHERE ID = $id AND Rank = 3';
   if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0){
      $noThreeArray[] = $row['ID'];
   }
 }
```

$noThreeArray now has the values you're after.

Comment: sure this works. but for now, I'm going to stick to a quick SQL only solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID FROM
(  
  SELECT ID, SUM(CASE WHEN Rank = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) flag FROM 
  (  
    SELECT ID, Rank FROM T1
  ) a  
  GROUP BY ID    
) b  
WHERE flag = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select ID as IDS from table where rank != 3 group by table.ID;
```

Comment: This will still return every ID, just not the specific row where the ID has a rank of 3...

Comment: Your query will return `11, 22, 33, 44, 55`.  He's looking for `11, 44, 55`.

Comment: I am using  group by table.ID So there is no question to repeat id

Comment: @DewasishMitruka thanks, but unfortunately this won't work. needless to say, this was the first thing I tried. but as @MichaelFredrickson has pointed out this will return all 5 unique IDs, we are looking for only 11, 44, 55. of course, `GROUP BY` won't repeat IDs but that is not what we're concerned with here.

Comment: well if you try than its ok but according to my know and experience it should work

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal seemingly, people were able to read and understand my question the way it is formatted - it got answered by a few too and then closed. I'm never going to read the formatting FAQ ever, not even for future reference.

Comment: @MickyWalia: (a) I was talking to Dewasish, which is why I wrote my comment on _his_ post, not yours; (b) Well that's highly ignorant of you.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal misread. well in that case, I take back what I said. cheers.

Comment: @DewasishMitruka: Hi. It is worth reading this page: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help It will help you format your posts (so other people do not have to help you).